# Rails: Render a status code without rendering a template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to make an ajax call to a rails (5.1.3) app. I want the targeted action in the controller to render a status code 200 and do nothing else. Here's how the action looks like.

```
  def some_delete_action
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        render status: 200, layout: false
      end
    end
  end
```

The issue is that rails tries to load the template associated with that action. Since there's no such template in my app, I get a `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error.

How can I render the status code without having rails try to reach for the template ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the [ActionController::Head](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/Head.html) and pass `:ok` as value:

```
# home_controller.rb
def do_nothing
  head :ok
end

# routes
get 'home/do_nothing

# request in view
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.get('<%= home_do_nothing_path %>')
</script>
```